# Knockout localisation dropdown selection

Tags: knockout.js, localization

I need some suggestion on setting up the localisation on knockout.

I use https://github.com/tfsjohan/Knockout-Localization-Binding for localisation but since it's using a static locale, I'm trying to use dropdown with binding.

```
<select data-bind="options: choices, value: selectedChoice"></select>
```

---

```
        <label for="name" data-bind="restext: 'name'"></label><br />

        <label data-bind="restext: 'email'"></label><br />

        <label data-bind="restext: 'street'"></label><br />

        <label data-bind="restext: 'zip'"></label><br />

        <label data-bind="restext: 'city'"></label><br />
```

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/efkgqwa5/1/ 
Basically I want the select option to load the value from the resource (en, sv, ...possibly other entry in the future) and the default chosen one is en. Then when I change to sv, it will make changes to other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well small modification will do the trick here just make `locale` as `self.locale` and reflect the changes in binding handlers too where you using locale variable

**ViewModel:**

```
 var vm = function(){
        var self=this;
        self.choices= ["en", "sv"];
        self.selectedChoice= ko.observable();
        self.name= ko.observable();
        self.email= ko.observable();
        self.locale=ko.observable('en');

       self.selectedChoice.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        self.locale(newValue); //updates everywhere
       });
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/efkgqwa5/3/)**